# Download Youtube Music song using youtube-dl

Tags: python, youtube-dl

Is it possible to download a song from Youtube Music using youtube-dl?
When I try to use the url to the song, I recieve this error message.

```
Need 11 character video id or the URL of the video. Got https://music.youtube.com/watch?v=BzsrqaLgdpk
```

Comment: Can send the code as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to just work. Make sure your youtube-dl is up to date i.e. `youtube-dl version 2020.09.20` you can find out your version using `youtube-dl -v`.